# How Can I Read Files directly from its url

Tags: python, csv, read.csv

```
url = 'https://cdn.wsform.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/currency.csv'

f = open(url, 'r')
print(f.read())
```

`Invalid argument: 'https://cdn.wsform.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/currency.csv'`

Is there any way so that i can read file from url, instead of downloading it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the standard `urllib.request.urlopen()` does exactly that:

```
from urllib import request

with request.urlopen('https://cdn.wsform.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/currency.csv') as f:
    print(f.read().decode())  # the decode turns the bytes into a string for printing
```

Just note that the file is opened as a file of `bytes`, since the function can't know if it's a text file or not.